# Need a good example of hiding/showing the grid columns for EXTJS 4.1.1a

Tags: grid, extjs4.1

I need a good example of hiding/showing the grid columns for EXTJS 4.1.1a, where I can click a button and show/hide a column based on the dataIndex name (for each column I have a itemcontextmenu that grabs the dataIndex name for that column), or have the column dynamically show/hide based on the dataIndex name grabbed.

I found a good example of hiding a column with a button that uses the column array 
( jsfiddle.net/MjFp3/ ), but this will not work for my scenario, because I need to have the ability to show/hide one or more columns from the grid after the grid has rendered with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find any native methods to look for column by `dataIndex` but here is a fiddle that uses ComponentQuery to search for the one it needs:

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/9YphM/